# Hand rigging with reverseIK fingers and pole vectors?

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I am currently trying to rig a walking hand and ran into some issues. Basically what I want to achieve is a Hand that is walking on its fingers (like the one in the show Wednesday for those who know).

I am struggling with the IK setup. I want the last joints of the fingers also to be able to bend inwards a bit to achieve specific poses (*like in the image included below. This is NOT my file! I just included it for reference*). I currently have a setup that kind of works. The problem with it is that the hand is now standing on middle joint of the fingers due to the IK sitting on that bone. When I set the IK to the last joint I loose the control over the bending inwards since I can't rotate the last joint anymore.

I have included the blend file.

[image: Hand Pose for reference (Not my file!)]

[image]